# Get And Use Facebook Access Token Without HTTPS

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, https, server-side

I have the following url for the first stage. getting `code` `http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=myappid&redirect_uri=myurl;state=e879888c-7090-4c09-98a5-ff361b30d55;scope=email`

and

```
url = String.Format(@"http://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&client_secret={2}&code={3}",FacebookAppId, redirectUrl, FacebookSecret, code);
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
var tokenVars = webClient.DownloadString(url);
var responseVars = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(tokenVars);
string access_token = responseVars["access_token"];
string data = webClient.DownloadString(String.Format("http://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={0}", access_token));
var jobject = JObject.Parse(data);
```

**400 BAD REQUEST** is returned.

Question: Is it possible to get facebook access token without connecting by  http **s** ?

Question: Is it possible to use access_token without **HTTPS?**  **NOT HTTP**

Answer (score 0):

for a secure you must take https, 
maybe if you aren't, some bad thing will show, @long process..
i just browse for your issue, and same thing